# Draw 3D bounding box of object in 2D (Processing)

Tags: python, 3d, processing

I would like to draw a 2d box around a 3d object and at the end, it should look like the following image:

[image]

I have already drawn a 3d Box and determined the corners (red balls) as well, but however I don't know what to do next or which steps should be taken next.

It would be a pleasure if someone could provide an algorithm or the next couple of steps to carry on working on it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Now, you have to map all 8 box corners into 2d (e.g. using the view and projection matrix of the 3d renderer), to determine min and max x and y coordinates. Then you can draw the box in 2d (the green one). _I have already drawn a 3d Box and determined the corners (red balls) as well_ How? What 3d rendering do you use? OpenGL?

Comment: @Scheff Thanks! for corners determination, I am using screenX and screenY.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I read the tag text but are as stupid as before. I thought it's done in Python. (Seeing one lang-tag I ignored the other.) My fault. I will google for Processing...

Comment: @Scheff I see. Processing uses Java syntax, but there is a plug-in for Python (and I think for some other languages, too). At least there is [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) (JavaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have 8 coordinates for both `x` and `y`

```
x=[123,455,544,677,345,333,677,322]
y=[734,543,654,234,132,654,321,123]
```

and assuming these 2 lists to be the x-y coordinates for a 3D box, then its 2D box can be found by this code:

```
x_min=min(x)
y_min=min(y)
x_max=max(x)
y_max=max(y)
```

And if you do something like this

```
cv2.rectangle(image,(x_min,y_min),(x_max,y_max),(255,0,0),1)
```

then you will get the result.